# Why make a new RoutedEventHandler when adding to a button's Click event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

What is the difference between:

```
this.btnConnect.Click += btnConnect_Click;
```

and:

```
this.btnConnect.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnConnect_Click);
```

It seems to work the same either way, but Visual Studio IntelliSense inserts the second example and I'm curious why.

My initial guess is that using the IntelliSense version makes it so that each button calls its own instance of the `RoutedEventHandler`, making it thread-safe?
And that using the first example, then each button would call the same instance of that method and they might step on each others feet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same thing, the first is just a syntactic sugar, i.e. compiler generates the same IL bytecode for both - there is always a delegate instance created.

IIRC, the first version of C# didn't allow the first syntax, it was introduced in C# 2.0.

Comment: Nice answer. I would add that the 2nd syntax can be called "explicit" while the 1st one has the delegate type inferred from the specified event; ReSharper flags the 2nd form as "redundant".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Lambda to new a RoutedEventHandler:

```
        new RoutedEventHandler(
            (sendItem, args) =>
            {
                //things you want to do
                IsTopMost = !IsTopMost;
                this.Topmost = IsTopMost;
                ((MenuItem) sendItem).Header = menuWords[0, ++menuClickCount[0]%2];
            })
```

Comment: Nice tip, although this doesn't address the question. You could also assign the lambda expression directly to the button click event without wrapping it in the `RoutedEventHandler`, i.e. `this.btnConnect.Click += (sender, args) => { /* do something */ };`